# Connected components from an adjacency matrix using Numpy or Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, graph, scipy

I've the following adjacency matrix:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Which can be drawn like that:

[image]

My goal is to identify the connected graph ABC and DEFG. It's seems that **Depth-First Search** algorithm is what I need and that Scipy [implemented it](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.depth_first_order.html). So here is my code:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import depth_first_order
import numpy as np

test = np.asarray([
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
])

graph = csr_matrix(test)
result = depth_first_order(graph, 0)
```

But I don't get the result:

```
>>> result
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([-9999,     0,     1, -9999, -9999, -9999, -9999]))
```

what's that `array([-9999,     0,     1, -9999, -9999, -9999, -9999])` ? Also, in the documentation, they talk about a sparse matrix not about an adjacency one. But an adjacency matrix seems to be a sparse matrix by definition so it's not clear for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While you could indeed use DFS to find the connected components, SciPy makes it even easier with [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components). With your example:

```
In [3]: connected_components(test)                                                              
Out[3]: (2, array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: I d'like to add a details that could seems obvious. The `array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]` is simply indexing connected components:  0 for ABC 1 for DEFG . I missed it when I found this function before you answered, probably because I was only having two graphs in my adjacency matrix.

Comment: What's the point of these labels? I don't see how one can retrieve the connected node's indices from the labels. Or does it serve a greater purpose?

Comment: @JaswantP: Rephrasing what snoobdogg already said ever so slightly, the labels denote the components and are indexed by the (ordered) vertices. That is, the first three vertices (a, b, c) belong to one component (0) while the other four vertices (d, e, f, g) belong to another component (1).

Answer (score 0):

Well to start, you have an undirected graph. Look at the documentation again and set the directed parameter to false since the default is True.

The first array you get is the nodes reachable from where you start (node 0 = node a) including your starting node.
So you start at node a and you can reach b and c. You can't reach the rest of the graph since you have a disconnected graph. DFS is doing what it is supposed to do. You will need to do DFS on the d node to get the second graph.